# fluentd not honoring log rotation

Tags: logging, rotation, fluent, fluentd, purge

Using fluent/fluentd:v1.3.2 docker image,
I am making use of file plugin , below is file plugin setting in fluentd.conf file

```
<store>
   @type file
   path /myproduct/test/logs
   append false
   compress gzip
</store>
```

Launched fluentd with following params:

```
/usr/bin/fluentd -c /test/fluent.conf --log-rotate-age 5 --log-rotate-size 1000
```

I am not seeing the files getting purged after generating 5 files . Please suggest if I am missing anything here in fluentd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

--log option was missing. Everything works as expected as soon as you provide --log parameter in fluentd command line.